# How to configure an .htaccess file on AWS EBS with Node.js as a Plattform and Apache as Proxy Server?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2

I am currently hosting a Nuxt3 SSR Webapp on an Elastic Beanstalk in AWS with Node as plattform and apache as proxy server. I deploy my project from gitlab through the ebs cli to aws:

```
- zip -r aws-artifact.zip ./server.js ./.env ./.output ./.htaccess ./.htpasswd ./.elasticbeanstalk
- eb deploy my-project
```

That works (don't know if there is a better way to do so or other hosting possibilities in AWS with SSR functionality), but the htaccess does not seem to work. I found that my `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` files are located in `/var/app/current`, where also my other files have been deployed to from gitlab.

The .htaccess file looks like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /var/app/current/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/test-htaccess$ /en
```

Whether the authentication nor the redirect works.

My goal is to create a user/password safe website and if redirects would work this way and in this context, would also be great.